# StackOverflowException unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, рекурсия

Создаю рекурсию, при при вызове получаю переполнение буфера.

```
public void square(Vec2int L, Vec2int R)
{
    int l = (R.x - L.x) / 2;
    if (l > 1) {
        Vec2int Center = new Vec2int (R.x - l, R.y - l);

        float a = map [L.x, L.y];
        float b = map [L.x, R.y];
        float c = map [R.x, R.y];
        float d = map [R.x, L.y];

        map [Center.x, Center.y] = (a + b + c + d) / 4 + Random.Range (-l * (Roughnees / size), l * (Roughnees / size));
    }
}

public void diamond(Vec2int point,int length)
{
    float a, b, c, d;

    if (point.y - length >= 0)
        a = map [point.x, point.y - length];
    else
        a = map[point.x, size - length];  

    if (point.x - length >= 0)
        b = map [point.x - length, point.y];
    else
        b = map [size - length, point.y];

    if (point.y + length < size)
        c = map [point.x, point.y + length];
    else
        c = map [point.x, length];    

    if (point.x + length < size)
        d = map [point.x + length, point.y];
    else
        d = map [length, point.y];

    map [point.x, point.y] = (a + b + c + d) / 4 + Random.Range (-length * (Roughnees / size), length * (Roughnees / size));
}

public void diamondSquare(Vec2int L,Vec2int R)
{
    int length = (R.x - L.x) / 2;

    Debug.Break();
    Debug.LogError(length);
    if (length > 1) {


        //square (L, R);
        Vec2int[] points = GetPoints (L, R, length);
        foreach (Vec2int elem in points) {
            diamond (elem, length);
        }
        square (L, new Vec2int (length, length));
        square (new Vec2int (length, length), R);
        square (points [0], points [3]);
        square (points [1], points [2]);

        diamondSquare (L, new Vec2int (length, length));
        diamondSquare (new Vec2int (length, length), R);
        diamondSquare (points [0], points [3]);
        diamondSquare (points [1], points [2]);
    }
}

public static Vec2int[] GetPoints(Vec2int L,Vec2int R, int length)
{
    return new Vec2int[] { 
        new Vec2int (L.x, L.y + length),
        new Vec2int (L.x + length, L.y), 
        new Vec2int (R.x, R.y - length),
        new Vec2int (R.x - length, R.y)
    };
}

public struct Vec2int
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public Vec2int(int x,int y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }
}
```

Comment: а что вы хотите сделать 4 вызовами функции рекурсивно? Особенно первыми 2. Почему части первых 2 вызовов не зависят от L или R?

Comment: `diamondSquare( new Vec2int (10, 11), new Vec2int (15,16));` такой вызов например всё уронит. http://ideone.com/fCYvDp В общем у вас в логике проблемы, а как править - вам виднее ну или вопрос дополните зачем всё это.

Comment: @pavel
Я пытаюсь реализовать алгоритм Diamond-Square для квадрата находится средняя точка которая делит его еще на 4, находятся центры ребер, и заново это все вызывается для каждого полученного квадрата.
[надеюсь понятно нарисовал](https://pp.vk.me/c636830/v636830401/3ba01/hEL0bg74P5Q.jpg)

Comment: @CGLike значит вывод какой? length всегда больше 1. Нужно чтоб, в конце концов стал меньше

Comment: @CGLike нет. Я пример даже привёл, где координаты явно не те считает. Не может в делении отрезка пополам использовать только его длина без координаты...

Comment: Может вам не целочисленное деление надо использовать а на дробь? `(R.x - L.x) / 2.0f`  потому что при целочисленном как раз получается что всегда целое число

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет, там как раз всё нормально. Это из классической темы: с 1 раза бинарный поиск без багов никто не кодит.

Comment: В рекурсии лучше ставить "ограничение" глубины. Тогда можно дебагером поймать допустим на глубине 100 шага, и посмотреть трассировкой почему зацикливается.

Comment: @nick_n_a знать бы как это делается

Comment: Пишется например так `public void square(Vec2int L, Vec2int R, int deep)` и при вызове первый с `deep=0`, а следующий  `square(L,R, deep + 1)`. Тогда можно поставить условие `if (deep>100) {...}`

Comment: @nick_n_a
Сейчас у меня если в условии рекурсии length больше пловины разрешения то все норм, в противном случае юнити просто вешается, и начинает по тихоньку жрать память все больше и больше, я даже Debub.Log увидеть не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Как я писал в комментарии, у вас логическая ошибка в вычислении позиций вложенных квадратов.

Пусть был вызов {10,11,15,16}

```
    diamondSquare ({10,11}, {8,8});
    diamondSquare ({8,8}, {15,16});
```

Что явно противоречит логике параметров.

Т.к. это квадраты, мне кажется передавать 4 числа вместо 3 только запутывает вас.

```
public static void diamondSquare(int xLeft, int yBottom, int length)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(xLeft +" "+yBottom + " "+length);
    if (length > 1) {
        length/=2;
        diamondSquare (xLeft,yBottom,length);
        diamondSquare (xLeft + length,yBottom,length);
        diamondSquare (xLeft,yBottom + length,length);
        diamondSquare (xLeft + length,yBottom + length,length);
    }
}
```

Оставил только рекурсивные вызовы, остальное тоже упрощается.

Кстати, вы уверены что вам нужен рекурсивный алгоритм? Это же можно сделать циклом (предполагаю, что размер - точная степень 2):

```
//for (int length=1; length <= MAX_LENGTH; length*=2)
for (int length=MAX_LENGTH; length > 0; length/=2)
   for (int xLeft= X_LEFT_BORDER; xLeft < X_RIGTH_BORDER; xLeft+=length)
      for (int yBottom = Y_BOTTOM_BORDER; yBottom < Y_TOP_BORDER; yBottom+=length)
         //Делать операцию, всё внутреннее уже вычислено
```

Comment: L и R это нижняя левая и правая верхняя точки, соответственно, а не отдельные координаты

Comment: @CGLike я как раз понимаю это. Но вам не нужны все 4 координаты, 3 хватит. + не квадрат точно не передадут.

Comment: там еще обязательный момент такой что diamond для текущего квадрата делается после нахождения центров соседних квадратов

Comment: Кажется я понял о чем вы

Comment: @CGLike вам с центрами удобнее работать а не с краями? Можете сразу передавать координату центра, это ничего не изменит.

Comment: При разрешении 16х16 и условии length > 5 все работает и первые координаты получаются: {0, 0}{ 7, 7} ||  {7, 7}{ 15, 15} || {0, 7}{ 8, 15} || {7, 0} { 15, 8}
А они правильные и картинка получается правильная.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, от переполнения буфера я избавился. Но всё проанализировав, я пришел к выводу, что невозможно реализовать этот алгоритм с помощью рекурсии.

Оставлю скрипт для *Unity*, что удалось реализовать:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DiaSqu : MonoBehaviour {
    public int size = 32;
    [Range(0,1f)]
    public float Roughnees = 0.5f;
    private float[,] map;

    void Awake()
    {
        size++;
    }

    void Start () {
        Material mat = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material;

        map = new float[size,size];
        Texture2D txt = new Texture2D (size, size);

        Vec2int Left = new Vec2int (0, 0);
        Vec2int Right = new Vec2int (size - 1, size - 1);

        map [Left.x, Left.y] = 0.5f;
        map [Left.x, Right.y] = 0.5f;
        map [Right.x, Left.y] = 0.5f;
        map [Right.x, Right.y] = 0.5f;

        int l = (Right.x - Left.x) / 2;

        square (Left, Right, l);
        diamondSquare(Left, Right, l);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                txt.SetPixel (i, j, new Color (map [i, j], map [i, j], map [i, j], 0));
            }
        }
        txt.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
        txt.Apply ();

        mat.mainTexture = txt;
    }

    public void square(Vec2int L, Vec2int R, int l)
    {
        Vec2int Center = new Vec2int (R.x - l, R.y - l);
        float a = map [L.x, L.y];
        float b = map [L.x, R.y];
        float c = map [R.x, R.y];
        float d = map [R.x, L.y];
        map [Center.x, Center.y] = (a + b + c + d) / 4 + Random.Range (-l / (size - 1) * (Roughnees), l / (size - 1) * (Roughnees));
    }

    public void diamond(Vec2int point,int l)
    {
        float a, b, c, d;

        if (point.y - l >= 0)
            a = map [point.x, point.y - l];
        else
            a = map[point.x, size - l];  

        if (point.x - l >= 0)
            b = map [point.x - l, point.y];
        else
            b = map [size - l, point.y];

        if (point.y + l < size)
            c = map [point.x, point.y + l];
        else
            c = map [point.x, l];    

        if (point.x + l < size)
            d = map [point.x + l, point.y];
        else
            d = map [l, point.y];

        map [point.x, point.y] = (a + b + c + d) / 4 + Random.Range (-l / (size - 1) * Roughnees, l / (size - 1) * Roughnees);
    }

    public void diamondSquare(Vec2int L, Vec2int R, int l)
    {
        if (l > 0) {
            Vec2int[] points = GetPoints(L, R, l);
            foreach (Vec2int elem in points) {
                diamond (elem, l);
            }
            square (L, new Vec2int (points [3].x, points [2].y), l);
            square (new Vec2int (points [3].x, points [2].y), R, l);
            square (points [0], points [1], l);
            square (points [3], points [2], l);

            diamondSquare (L, new Vec2int (points [3].x, points [2].y), l / 2);
            diamondSquare (new Vec2int (points [3].x, points [2].y), R, l / 2);
            diamondSquare (points [0], points [1], l / 2);
            diamondSquare (points [3], points [2], l / 2);
        }
    }

    public static Vec2int[] GetPoints(Vec2int L, Vec2int R, int l)
    {
        return new Vec2int[] {
            new Vec2int (L.x, L.y + l),
            new Vec2int (R.x - l, R.y),
            new Vec2int (R.x, R.y - l),
            new Vec2int (L.x + l, L.y)
        };
    }
    // 0-3 это индексы массива
    //  p---- 1 ----p
    //  |           |
    //  0           2
    //  |           |
    //  p---- 3 ----p

    public struct Vec2int
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public Vec2int(int x,int y){
            this.x=x;
            this.y=y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Ответы-ссылки могут стать недействительными в случае изменения страницы, на которую дана ссылка.

Comment: @Zufir я помог ему, друх. Можешь спать спокойно)

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но с ссылкой ничего не случилось бы.